# How to memorize value to use it after flatMap?

Tags: javascript, bacon.js, flatmap

```js
Bacon.fromArray(list)
    .flatMap(function(user){
        return Bacon.fromCallback(user, 'getClients');
    })
    .onValue(function(clients){
        // need `user` object some how
    })
;
```

Need `user` object in `onValue` callback

Comment: one ways is to add map like `return Bacon.fromCallback(user, 'getClients').map(function(val){ return {user: user, clients: val} })`

Comment: Related: [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily with [`combineAsArray`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#bacon-combineasarray-multiple-streams) or [`combineTemplate`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#bacon-combinetemplate). They allow combining streams/properties and constant values. Here is an example using `combineAsArray`:

```
Bacon.fromArray(list)
  .flatMap(function(user){
    return Bacon.combineAsArray(
      user, Bacon.fromCallback(user, 'getClients')
    )
  })
  .onValues(function(user, clients){
    // handle result here
  })
```